# Replace specific content from div with html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace some portion of content from a div with inside wrapped html elements.

> **Actual content:**

```
line 120, col 8: The relative URL 'Helloo' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a' is disallowed. (see undefined)line 136, col 16: The relative URL 'fasdf' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a' is disallowed. (see undefined)line 155, col 12: Missing URL for attribute 'action-xhr' in tag 'form'. (see https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form)
```

> **Expected output:**

```
    <ul>
      <li>The relative URL 'Helloo' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a' is disallowed. (see undefined)</li>
      <li>The relative URL 'fasdf' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a' is disallowed. (see undefined)</li>
      <li>Missing URL for attribute 'action-xhr' in tag 'form'. (see https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form)</li>
    </ul>
```

- Remove line no information (line numbers will be dynamically generated)
- Create list item for each error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very complicated. **Regex** can help you. I used regex to find first of every line and used **`.split()`** to split lines

```
str = str.split(/line \d+, col \d+: /g).filter(x => x != "").map(x => `<li>${x}</li>`).join('')
str = `<ul>${str}</ul>`
```

```js
let str = `line 120, col 8: The relative URL 'Helloo' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a' is disallowed. (see undefined)line 136, col 16: The relative URL 'fasdf' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a' is disallowed. (see undefined)line 155, col 12: Missing URL for attribute 'action-xhr' in tag 'form'. (see https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form)`;

str = str.split(/line \d+, col \d+: /g).filter(x => x != "").map(x => `<li>${x}</li>`).join('')
str = `<ul>${str}</ul>`

console.log(str)
```